# Hide the DataGrid while TextBox Loses its Focus If DataGrid is not Focused

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, textbox, focus

I have a textbox and DataGrid

While textbox loses the focus and if DataGrid is not Focused then I want to Hide the DataGrid.

I use the below code.

```
Private Sub txt_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles txt.LostFocus

    If DataGrid1.IsFocused = False Then
        DataGrid1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    End If

End Sub
```

using this code even if I click on any Item on DataGrid the DataGrid hides.

Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is... the behaviour you describe is consistent with your code.

The behaviour might be different from what you would expect...
I think when the **TextBox loses focus** the DataGrid will never have focus because the **TextBox didn't finish losing focus**. Is that the problem?

If that's the problem, you may add some kind of delay before hiding DataGrid (in a non blocking way of course). You can create a new Thread, do a Sleep(500) on that thread before hiding the control, and see what happens.
You also need to take care because only the UI thread may change visible controls, but you may ask further help if you choose to do that.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the textbox lostfocus even fired .. the gridview not focused yet ..

So, add something like this

```
Dim lDGVFocused as Boolean

Private Sub Datagrid1_Enter( ... ) ...

  lDGVFocused = True

End Sub

Private Sub Datagrid1_LostFocus( ... ) ...

  lDGVFocused = False

End Sub

Private Sub txt_LostFocus( ... ) ...

    If not lDGVFocused then DataGrid1.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub txt_GotFocus( ... ) ...

   DataGrid1.Visible = True

End Sub
```